# Spring At least one base package must be specified exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, compiler-errors

When I'm compiling my project it gives this error and stop compiling

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one base package must be
>   specified

Why this exception happen and How I solve it.

Comment: share your application-context.xml

Comment: Just check whether you have mentioned the full package path of Controllers or services properly.

Comment: The problem could be your have configured annotation driven context configuration but does not have any `component-scan` path specified

Comment: Try adding `<context:component-scan base-package="<your-app-base-package>"`

Comment: Thanks for answers. context:component-scan base-package was empty.

Comment: @AmithMendis if any of our answer resolved your query, you can accept it as your answer isn't it.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Spring Doc

> Spring provides the capability of automatically detecting 'stereotyped' classes and registering corresponding BeanDefinitions with the ApplicationContext. To autodetect these classes and register the corresponding beans requires the inclusion of the following element in XML where 'basePackage' would be a common parent package for the two classes (or alternatively a comma-separated list could be specified that included the parent package of each class).

Hence your application-context should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>

</beans>
```

to enable your package to get scanned via `component-scan` you should annotate your java class with respective annotation as per the requirement. Like `@Controllers` or `@Service` etc.
See the full details [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s12.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="Your package">

</context:component-scan>
```

try adding this in you configuration file

Answer (score 1):

From my comments above

The reason could be you have annotation driven context configuration enabled (`<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>`) in you application context, but you have to provided any base package to scan for spring beans.

Add the root package of your application as the base package to scan for bean definitions

```
<context:component-scan base-package="<your-app-base-package>"/>
```