# spring boot starter package error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Now i am learning spring boot,but i find a question,i don't know why this happen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqRes.png]

this is structure of my code, SampleController.java at src/main/java as spring boot reference says [spring boot reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application). notice "package controller"，if there are no package message, i can't run the code, the error message is:

[image: error message]

but if i add package message,even this is a wrong package message, the code can run.

so, i want to know this is my mistake or spring boot reference mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring At least one base package must be specified exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079364/spring-at-least-one-base-package-must-be-specified-exception)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put springboot Main class right into the main/java directory, and even in any java project you're not recommended that way. Put all these stuff in a package instead.

Answer (score 0):

When a class does not include a package declaration, it is considered to be in the “default package”. The use of the “default package” is generally discouraged and should be avoided. It can cause particular problems for Spring Boot applications that use the @ComponentScan, @EntityScan, or @SpringBootApplication annotations, since every class from every jar is read.